# Amadeus Soap Header 4.0 Authentication Stateless

Tags: php, xml, soap, amadeus

I am sharing my code and problem

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$UUID = vsprintf( '%s%s-%s-%s-%s-%s%s%s', str_split(bin2hex(random_bytes(16)), 4) );
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$t = microtime(true);
$micro = sprintf("%03d",($t - floor($t)) * 1000);
$date = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro) );
$timestamp = $date->format("Y-m-d\TH:i:s").$micro . 'Z';
$nonce = mt_rand(10000000, 99999999);
$nounce = base64_encode($nonce);
$password = "02pOq3pZ2CkIhi";
$passSHA = base64_encode(sha1($nonce . $timestamp . sha1($password, true), true));
```

Here is my soap header 4.0 request

```
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soap:Header>
    <add:MessageID xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">83ff5004-559f- 
93ba-ba49-367ff11edd98</add:MessageID>
    <add:Action xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"> 
http://webservices.amadeus.com/SERVICE</add:Action>
    <add:To 
 xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"> 
 https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWAAAAAK</add:To>
    <oas:Security xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss- 
 wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <oas:UsernameToken xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 
 200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" oas1:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <oas:Username>WSAAKAAA</oas:Username>
            <oas:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis- 
  200401-wss-soapmessage-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Yzk3YjdiYTY5ZjkxMTlhNjdhNGQ=. 
  </oas:Nonce>
            <oas:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401- 
   wss-usernametoken-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">9S3hM6i4M11fOYpba3oWYolguUs=. 
  </oas:Password>
           <oas1:Created>2023-05-13T15:30:20:880Z</oas1:Created>
        </oas:UsernameToken>
    </oas:Security>
    <AMA_SecurityHostedUser xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Security_v1">
        <UserID POS_Type="1" PseudoCityCode="DMMS228XU" AgentDutyCode="SU" 
 RequestorType="U"/>
    </AMA_SecurityHostedUser>
 </soap:Header>
 <soap:Body>
    <Hotel_List>
        <scrollingInformation>
            <displayRequest>050</displayRequest>
            <maxNumberItems>99</maxNumberItems>
        </scrollingInformation>
        <porInfo>
            <hotelRefPointInfo>
                <porGeocode>
                    <porLongitude>235100</porLongitude>
                    <porLatitude>4885670</porLatitude>
                </porGeocode>
                <radiusSearch>10</radiusSearch>
                <distanceDecimalPoint>1</distanceDecimalPoint>
                <measureUnit>G</measureUnit>
            </hotelRefPointInfo>
        </porInfo>
    </Hotel_List>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I Have applied all required terms for amadeus authentication but doesn't working

Here is my response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault>. 
<faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring> 12|Presentation|soap message header 
incorrect</faultstring><faultactor>SI:muxDZ2</faultactor></soap:Fault></soap:Body>. 
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am using end point

End Point: https://nodeD1.test.webservices.amadeus.com

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Hi Kayes, what transaction is this?   
I don't see a Hotel_List SOAP webservice, I can only see it listed as a REST webservice  

Do you have a link to the soap documentation for that webservice?  

In the code above you have the 
`<add:Action xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://webservices.amadeus.com/SERVICE</add:Action>`

"SERVICE" should have the webservice name/version like this for the PNR_Retrieve webservice    

`<add:Action xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://webservices.amadeus.com/PNRRET_15_1_1A</add:Action>`

Comment: I am searching hotel list  - http://webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWAAAAAK/Hotel_List_04_2_1A

Comment: Now getting this error : n<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>wsse:InvalidSecurityToken</faultcode><faultstring>An invalid security token was provided</faultstring><faultactor>SI:muxDZ2</faultactor></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>

Comment: For support to Enterprise related questions you can get in touch directly with your account manager.

Comment: "invalid security token was provided" suggests to me an error with <oas1:Created> date format. Have you made changes since originally posting the question?